# tomcat returns 404 on project root url

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, deployment, devops, war

spring-boot has a Controller called MainController which contains the code below

```
@Controller
public class MainController {
@GetMapping("/")
public String what() {
    return "hello";
 }
}
```

and this is the @SpringBootApplication class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SamyarApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder 
 builder) {
    return builder.sources(SamyarApplication.class);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SamyarApplication.class, args);
}
}
```

and I build a war file from my project

when I move that to the Tomcat "web apps" directory

and call it, tomcat returns 404 error

this is the ls of tomcat web apps directory

```
root@vm8944397922:/opt/tomcat/webapps# ls
    ROOT  examples      manager            samyar-gameland-1.war
    docs  host-manager  samyar-gameland-1
```

this is the URL

HTTP://my-server-ip:8080/samyar-gameland-1

Comment: Which version of Tomcat are you using?

Comment: If you need to deploy Spring Boot applications by producing a `war` file, you need to provide some special configurations. This is well explained in the docs, see [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto.traditional-deployment)

Comment: @PiotrP.karwasz version 9

Comment: @MatheusCirillo I did but is still now working

Comment: Can you add the class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` to the question?

Comment: @PiotrP.karwasz I did it